# How to display/refresh related fields in edit forms

Tags: odoo

I have an object `shipment` with a field `product` of type related many2one that references many2one object `contract` which has one product (many2one). When I create a shipment, the product does not get displayed until I save the shipment. Also, when editing, the product does not change with the contract.

I tried to create onchange event that returns the new product value but it did not work.

Is their a method to refresh related fields when the relation changes?

- Mohammad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that `sales.order` and `stock.picking` standard objects are very close to what you need. You´ll be better off extending standard objects instead of creating new ones from scratch.

Regarding your question, you need `on_change` behaviour, so you should try to fix the method that´s not working. 
In 6.1 you have a good example for this. See the `crm_base` object in `crm/crm.py`.

You can see it in action in the CRM Lead form): when selecting a Partner, the Address and e-mail are automatically filled. You need to also have a look at the view id `crm_case_form_view_oppor` in `crm\crm_lead_view.xml`, to check how the method is used.

The model code is:

```
def onchange_partner_address_id(self, cr, uid, ids, add, email=False):
    """This function returns value of partner email based on Partner Address
    :param ids: List of case IDs
    :param add: Id of Partner's address
    :param email: Partner's email ID
    """
    data = {'value': {'email_from': False, 'phone':False}}
    if add:
        address = self.pool.get('res.partner.address').browse(cr, uid, add)
        data['value'] = {'email_from': address and address.email or False ,
                         'phone':  address and address.phone or False}
    if 'phone' not in self._columns:
        del data['value']['phone']
    return data

def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part, email=False):
    """This function returns value of partner address based on partner
    :param ids: List of case IDs
    :param part: Partner's id
    :param email: Partner's email ID
    """
    data={}
    if  part:
        addr = self.pool.get('res.partner').address_get(cr, uid, [part], ['contact'])
        data = {'partner_address_id': addr['contact']}
        data.update(self.onchange_partner_address_id(cr, uid, ids, addr['contact'])['value'])
    return {'value': data}
```

The view side code is:

```
<field name="partner_id" select="1" colspan="2" 
  on_change="onchange_partner_id(partner_id, email_from)" string="Customer" />
<field name="partner_address_id" string="Contact" colspan="1"
  on_change="onchange_partner_address_id(partner_address_id, email_from)" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. my `contract` is actually _inherits from `purchase.order`. Also, the `shipment` _inherits from `account.analytic.account` and links to multiple `stock.picking`. My `onchange` was indeed broken. Thanks.

Comment: You probably ment the other way around: `contract` inherits from `account.analytic.account` and `shipment`inherits from `purchase.order`.

Comment: No. the `contract` is a long term purchase contract with overseas supplier. `shipment` (actually it is `vessel`) _inherits from `account.analytic.account` because each product shipment/vessel is handled as a project with its own expenses and P&L.

Answer (score 2):

Well Ali,

Yes in case of fields related you are right the values will be displayed only when you save the record. Cause you save the record the ORM will link the related field values and the web page will read back it and show you back.

But yes to show the values immediately  on your from you can User the `on_change` that has ability to values of the any field when you make change the field itself.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The `onchange` was broken so I fixed it.

Comment: @firebug: on_change is not being triggered on related (m20) field.